# Querying AWS using Packer

Tags: amazon-web-services, packer

I'm using Packer to query AWS to find an AMI to use as a source AMI. I'd like to find AMI by tags. Here is my code.

```
"source_ami_filter": {
  "filters": {
    "tag": "type=Ubuntu Base"
  },
  "owners": ["self"],
  "most_recent": true
}
```

which receives this error

`amazon-ebs: Error querying AMI: InvalidParameterValue: The filter 'Filter.tag' is invalid`

I can't for the life of me figure out how to format that filter. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your sample code is very close, but the tag name should be specified in the filters key instead of the value.

This modification of your code should work to find the AMI with a "type" tag containing the value "Ubuntu Base":

```
"source_ami_filter": {
  "filters": {
    "tag:type": "Ubuntu Base"
  },
  "owners": ["self"],
  "most_recent": true
}
```

The Packer documentation for [source_ami_filter](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/amazon-ebs.html#source_ami_filter) explains that "any filter described in the docs for DescribeImages is valid."

Then the AWS EC2 documentation for [DescribeImages](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeImages.html) shows that a filter for a value contained in a given tag should use the format, *tag:key=value*:

> tag:key=value - The key/value combination of a tag assigned to the resource. Specify the key of the tag in the filter name and the value of the tag in the filter value. For example, for the tag Purpose=X, specify tag:Purpose for the filter name and X for the filter value.